# React Native <NavigationContainer> not styling

Tags: react-native

Building a Signal clone and trying to have my  to be styled from my StyleSheet. Here is the code

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import RegisterScreen from "./screens/RegisterScreen";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const globalScreenOptions = {
  headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#2C6BED" },
  headerTitleStyle: { color: "white" },
  headerTintColor: "white",
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={globalScreenOptions}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

I have tried to put everything in a   tag to get it to be affected by the StyleSheet, but that won't work either. I'm unable to find any other similar posts to this question

Comment: Tried to put it in a View tag, but no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the styles created by [`StyleSheet.create`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet), you need to actually use them in an element. For example (from the stylesheet docs):

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}> {/* <-- note style attribute */}
    <Text style={styles.title}>React Native</Text>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
    backgroundColor: "#eaeaea"
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: 16,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    textAlign: "center",
  }
});

export default App;
```